# Http PUT to a JSON store

Tags: json, http, couchdb, put, livecode

What is the LiveCode equivalent of the following JavaScript code snippet?

```
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("PUT", theURLoftheNoSQLstore, false);  
            req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', mimeType);
            req.send(theJSONobjString);
```

The parameters have been defined as

```
            theJSONobj   = {};
            theJSONobj["aKey"] = "aValue";
            theJSONobj["anotherKey"] = 123;
            theJSONobj["note"] = "some note about the issue";
            theJSONobjString = JSON.stringify(theJSONobj);
            theURLoftheNoSQLstore ="http://localhost:5984/thedb/thekey"

            mimeType="application/json";
```

**Note**

Setting the mimeType has been added for completeness. However for posting to the JSON store it is not necessary as that is the default in this case (couchDB).

**References**

[mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mime-types/info)
[XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlhttprequest/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LiveCode equivalent of your JavaScript should be:

```
set the httpHeaders to "Content-Type: application/json"
put "[" into myJson
// add one record
put "{'key1':'data1','key2':'data2'}" after myJson
// don't forget commas between multiple records
put "]" after myJson
// next line may not work with more complex data
replace "'" with quote in myJson
// server must be able to process PUT
put myJson into URL "http://localhost:5984/thedb/thekey"
put the result into rslt
if rslt is not empty then
  beep
  answer error rslt
end if
```

Comment: works fine with couchdb in case you send a JSON object and not a JSON array. So only {"key1":"data1","key2":"data2"} and not [{"key1":"data1","key2":"data2"}]

Comment: I don't think that Hannes mentioned mobile anywhere, or did I overlook it?

Comment: No, you didn't it was just a note just in-case

Comment: I have tested it on Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) with LiveCode 6.0 so far. [More](http://cnx.org/content/m33970/latest/) on the db used...